# How to set the opacity for a plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, transparency, matlab-figure

I have some data to be plotted in one figure. Noise data is ruining other data. How can I change the transparency level of a given data? In my case, I'm using `hold all` command for plotting several data. One of the solution is to change the `LineWidth` but I couldn't find a way for transparency option. I've tried `alpha` as follows

`plot( noise_x, 'k', 'LineWidth', 1, 'alpha', 0.2)`

but with no luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the [**introduction of the new graphic engine HG2**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/10/03/matlab-r2014b-graphics-part-1-features-of-the-new-graphics-system/) in **Matlab R2014b**, things got pretty easy. One just needs to dig a little.

The color property now contains a forth value for opacity/transparency/face-alpha, so that's all you need to change:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100); y = x.^2;
p1 = plot(x,y,'LineWidth',5); hold on
p2 = plot(x,-y+y(1),'LineWidth',5);

% // forth value sets opacity
p1.Color(4) = 0.5;
p2.Color(4) = 0.5;
```

[image]

Even color gradients are [**nothing special anymore**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694037/2605073).

Comment: I have Matlab R2014a.

Comment: @CroCo That's a bummer. Then you need to go for [Benoits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32059466/2605073) answer or, if you don't want to use external functions, follow my link to [Hoki's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31699594/2605073).

Comment: Nice one I did not know about that 4th color property thanks!

Comment: @thewaywewalk It is a fantastic answer!! could you also add some notes on the other 3 colour properties?

Comment: You mean `Color(1:3)`? These are just the normalized rgb values matlab uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [patchline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m) submission from the File Exchange, in which you can manipulate line objects as if they were patch objects; i.e. assign them transparency (alpha) values.

Here is some sample code using the function:

```
clc;clear;close all

n = 10;
x = 1:n;

y1 = rand(1,n);
y2 = rand(1,n);
y3 = rand(1,n);

Y = [y1;y2;y3];

linestyles = {'-';'-';'--'};
colors = {'r';'k';'b'};
alphavalues = [.2 .5 .8];

hold on
for k = 1:3
    patchline(x,Y(k,:),'linestyle',linestyles{k},'edgecolor',colors{k},'linewidth',4,'edgealpha',alphavalues(k))
end
```

and output:

[image]

Comment: this doesn't automatically fill the x axis values. In my case, I have only y values. This function throws out an error.

Comment: @CroCo `x` is just `x = 1:numel(y)`, isn't it?

Comment: This code similar to my case `x = 0:0.01:pi;
patchline(sin(x))`. This throws out an error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` If I use `plot(sin(x))`, there is no error.

Comment: can you post the whole code that reproduces the error as an edit to your question?

Comment: @Benoit_11, I've posted it in my comment above yours. Basically, `plot` does the job without explicitly providing the x-axis values. This is not the case with `patchline`. Is there a way to overcome this problem?