# How to use progressive coloring with plot3?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to use `plot3` with varying colors as the array index progresses.

I have 3 variables: `x`, `y`, `z`.
All of these variables contain values in the timeline progress.

For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
plot3(x, y, z, 'o')
```

I'd like to see a change of color from (`x(1), y(1), z(1)`) to the last value in the plot (`x(5), y(5), z(5)`). How can I change this color dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to go here, in my opinion, is to use [`scatter3`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html), where you can specify the colour value explicitly:

```matlab
scatter3(x,y,z,3,1:numel(x))
```

where `3` would be the size argument and `1:numel(x)` gives increasing colours. Afterward you can choose your colour map as usual.

[image]

Using `plot3` you could do the same, but it requires a loop:

```matlab
cMap = jet(numel(x));  % Generates colours on the desired map

figure
hold on  % Force figure to stay open, rather than overwriting
for ii = 1:numel(x)
    % Plot each point separately
    plot3(x(ii), y(ii), z(ii), 'o', 'color',cMap(ii,:))
end
```

[image]

I'd only use the `plot3` option in case you want successively coloured lines between elements, which `scatter3` can't do:

```matlab
cMap = jet(numel(x));  % Generates colours on the desired map

figure
hold on  % Force figure to stay open, rather than overwriting
for ii = 1:numel(x)-1
    % Plot each line element separately
    plot3(x(ii:ii+1), y(ii:ii+1), z(ii:ii+1), 'o-', 'color',cMap(ii,:))
end
% Redraw the last point to give it a separate colour as well
plot3(x(ii+1), y(ii+1), z(ii+1), 'o', 'color',cMap(ii+1,:))
```

[image]

---

<sub>NB: tested and exported images on R2007b, cross-checked the syntax with R2021b docs</sub>

Comment: For the last part: if you want the color to _gradually_ change you can use the trick [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5042-how-do-i-vary-color-along-a-2d-line): `surface([x; x],[y; y],[z; z],[1:numel(x); 1:numel(x)], 'facecol','no','edgecol','interp','linew',1.5)`

Comment: yes to the trick above, and/or you can use any of the answer to this question: [Change color of 2D plot line depending on 3rd value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685078/3460361)